# Convert channel mention to discord text channel object

Tags: python, discord.py

Question may be worded oddly, but I'm trying to have a function take a channel mention and a message (string) as arguments; then send the message to the channel mentioned. This function is within in a class (cog) so that's why it has `self`:

```py
# Discord Imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class Author_Only(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self,bot):
    self.bot=bot

  @commands.command(
  brief='Sends a message using Doge Bot')
  async def announce(self,ctx,channel,*,message:str): # I can't seem to find the proper conversion for a text channel, 
    await ctx.message.delete()                        # since you can do a similar thing with mentioning someone
    await channel.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly already know how to make sure the message is a string, well for a channel just instead of

> str

do

> discord.TextChannel

Example below

```
#Discord Imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class Author_Only(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command(brief="Sends a message using doge bot")
    async def announce(self, ctx, channel: discord.Channel, *, message: str):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await channel.send(message)
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to come back and answer this question, as I already found the solution a long time ago from the discord.py discord server; but thank you for answering an older question though.

Comment: Yeah no problem